# Slim 3 with Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, slim

I'm develping (or trying too) a web application with angularjs and Slim 3.
What I am trying to achieve is the following:
- an index.phtml (like the Slim skeleton) which would normally be the index.html of an Angular app. 
- the Slim routes.php contains all API routes in a group

```
$app->group('/api', function () { 
$this->get('/post', function ($request, $response, $args) { ...
```

- at the end of the routes.php a route for rendering the index.phtml

  $app->get('/[{:anything}]', function ($request, $response, $args) { return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml', $args); });

I was hoping the [{:anything}] would create a catchall route which rendered the index.phtml and have Angular parse the [{:anything}] using it's router. Unfortunately it doesn't.
Does anyone have an idea?

I know I could make a index.hml for Angular and a api/ directory with a index.php for SIlm, I've done it this way. But I'd really have it working the way I described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: removing the : from :anything did the trick. Still thinking too much in Slim 2 logic.

Comment: You should not do... $app->get('/[{:anything}]' as it will literally capture all GET routes...

Comment: Exactly. Slim 3 router is based on FastRoute by nikic. It processes the routes in the order they are defined. So first I define all API routes with the $app->group( and then all other routes are caught by the catchall route $app->get([{anything:.+}], which will be handled by Angular's router. Just as intended.